# Jquery click event android

Tags: jquery, mobile, touch

im bit confused about click event and touch screens,
i've red that it doesnt work with mobile devices,
but i was just testing with jquery 1.7
and click events lik: "$("#testlink").on("click..."  works perfect on my mobile with android 2.2
im not using any extra library just standard jquery 1.7.
Does it mean that jquery 1.7 already works with touch screens and we don't have to use touchstart events?

Comment: I believe that when you just "tap" on your screen, a click event will be fired as usual. But jQuery does not have native support for more complex touch-events like pinch-to-zoom, swipe etc., from what I know.

Comment: it is not about jquery not understanding touch events, but that mobile browsers don't recognize some events. like i've read that we should use touchstart instead of mousedown/click. but when im testing now these 2 events (mousedown/click) they are working fine in android . so not sure why do we have to use libraries like for example: http://touchpunch.furf.com/ for jqueryui?